# Nextjs13.5 hosting on ISS Window

Tags: routes, deployment, server, hosting, next.js13

I am try to host my Nextjs@13.5 starter code on ISS to test my configuration because later i will host my actual nextJS application. I want to use default page routing and Image optimization of nextjs13.But when i access my website on browser it showing infinite without any error message. I gave proper permission and try to run port 80
1)I have installed URL rewriting

2)IISNODE also

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I tried with server.js and web.config then i tried with only web.config because somewhere i read, i don't need server.js if i want to use default nextjs page routing image optimization.
I want proper configuration of web.config file and IIS configuration.
i